# How does prefixing work exactly when signing messages?

Tags: solidity, web3js

Here's a message I've signed using `web3` :

```
> web3.eth.sign(web3.utils.soliditySha3("xyz"), "0x00a329c0648769A73afAc7F9381E08FB43dBEA72", "testing").then(console.log);
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
> 0xbddd506ff736e03c1c25eaefbc7d73ead76c34135bd7d2f0c626735a7246ac612ed1b71915e8e9131ef7b0711ac2cfef62cbef2e22d4c1cce8f273fd285240cb1b
```

If one tries to verify it using [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/verifySig) with:

```
[Step 1] Address: 0x00a329c0648769A73afAc7F9381E08FB43dBEA72
[Step 2] Message Signature Hash: 0xbddd506ff736e03c1c25eaefbc7d73ead76c34135bd7d2f0c626735a7246ac612ed1b71915e8e9131ef7b0711ac2cfef62cbef2e22d4c1cce8f273fd285240cb1b
[Step 3] Enter the original Message that was signed: xyz
```

Result would be `Message Signature (with Geth Prefix) Verified. Pass!`

But [etherchain](https://etherchain.org/verify/signature) is giving `Invalid signature!` which I suppose is because of the prefix.

I've tried these as Message but none works :

```
\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32xyz
\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n320x9dd2c369a187b4e6b9c402f030e50743e619301ea62aa4c0737d4ef7e10a3d49
\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n329dd2c369a187b4e6b9c402f030e50743e619301ea62aa4c0737d4ef7e10a3d49
\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32ÒÃi¡´æ¹Äð0åCæ0¦*¤Às}N÷á
=I
```

What is the right *Message*?

---

**Back to `web3`**

```
> web3.eth.accounts.sign("xyz","0x177be4516179d50d87ed895505f84ea95189d8a74b59a54adac0466cfc436aaa")
{ message: 'xyz',
  messageHash: 
'0x47c659bdb805bd39452735d0acd70fafc43394fccbcd22897f98e58fd97c32f4',
  v: '0x1b',
  r: '0x...',
  s: '0x...',
  signature: '0x...' }
```

`messageHash` stays the same for every key, which is

```
> web3.utils.sha3("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n3xyz")
'0x47c659bdb805bd39452735d0acd70fafc43394fccbcd22897f98e58fd97c32f4'
```

**Question 1:** In solidity the prefix has to be `\n32` instead of `\n3` for `ecrecover` to work. Why?

**Question 2:** Why I am getting a wrong public address when:

```
> web3.eth.accounts.recover("0x47c659bdb805bd39452735d0acd70fafc43394fccbcd22897f98e58fd97c32f4", "0x1b", "0xbddd506ff736e03c1c25eaefbc7d73ead76c34135bd7d2f0c626735a7246ac61", "0x2ed1b71915e8e9131ef7b0711ac2cfef62cbef2e22d4c1cce8f273fd285240cb")
'0xf70Ec3f5A4eeDDc0fce9Ebe244CaBD22B5A49C95' !!!!!
```

Comment: This should now be resolved. Do you still have an issue?

Answer (score 2):

As of today (18th August 2017) prefixing **does not** work.

That is to say there is no consistent specification, and clients implement signature generation in different ways.

I.E. Something signed in one place won't necessarily validate in another place if they have done the signing in a different way.

This is currently being [debated](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/683). Please share your views.